# No me ejecuta el comando ssh

Tags: python, linux, python-3.7, python-3.9

Perdonarme pero soy nuevo en esto de *python* y esto me está volviendo loco.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
def conexion_ssh(fase): #Realizar la conexión SSH
    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(host, username=user, password=passw)
        sesion = client.get_transport().open_session()
        if sesion.active:
            sesion.exec_command(fase)
            result = sesion.recv(1024).decode()
            #print(result)
            if result.find("Error: 0") >= 0:
                print('Encontrado Error: 0, continuamos siguiente fase.')
            else:
                print(result)
                print('Fallo, Error no es = 0')
                sys.exit()

        client.close()

    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
        print(f'** Autenticación fallida, no se ha establecido la conexión. **')
        sys.exit()
```

La cosa es que cuando le paso el comando que tiene que ejecutar en `sesion.exec_command(fase)` no me la ejecuta al completo (se queda al principio) y no consigo que llegue al final de la ejecución para que aparezca:

> Error: 0

Entonces siempre me entra en el *else*.

¿Alguna idea de que puede fallar? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: bienvenid@ a SO! Cual es el valor de `result`?

Comment: Hola! pues result deveria ser el resultado de la ejecución de sesion.exec_command(fase) que lo recoge aqui "result = sesion.recv(1024).decode()" (a no ser que lo tenga mal).

Cogí el ejemplo de youtube de codigo facilito

Comment: Hay un `print` que está comentado. Podrías descomentarlo y decirnos cual es el valor de `result`?

Comment: Ese printf es el resultado del comando que le paso por "fase", por ejemplo si lanzo un export que tarda en ejecutarse se queda en mitad y no te lo termina, se queda en mitad el resultado. 

Osea si yo lanzo el export directamente desde el servidor, por pantalla sale un chorrazo y al final sale "ERROR: 0". Pues eso necesito que salga por python para saber si tengo que lanzar el siguiente y automatizarlo. No se si me explico (^_^¡)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... creo que entiendo por donde vienen los tiros. Cuando indicas `sesion.recv(1024)` le pides al canal que se quede esperando 1024 bytes. Si la salida del comando tiene menos de 1024 bytes.... pues se va a bloquear la ejecución.

Si quieres obtener la salida de la ejecución, creo que te queda mejor leer lo que hay en stdout (que es uno de los valores de la tupla que devuelve exec_command):

```
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = sesion.exec_command(fase)
```

Como nota al margen, tienes que manejar los 3 streams como si fueran
`archivos`.

Comment: ¿Entonces mi script deberia quedar asi...?

.....
        if sesion.active:
            (stdin, stdout, stderr) = sesion.exec_command(fase)
            
            if stdout.find("Error: 0") >= 0:
                print('Encontrado Error: 0, continuamos siguiente fase.')
            else:
                print(stdout)
                print('Fallo, Error no es = 0')
                sys.exit()

        client.close()

    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
        print(f'** Autenticación fallida, no se ha establecido la conexión. **')
        sys.exit()

Comment: No. `stdout` es como un archivo asi que el contenido se lo debes sacar tal cual se hace con un archivo para luego analizarlo.

Comment: Stdout no me ha servido.... ¿si lo tengo que tratar como un archivo, no funcionaria con el stdout.find? Tampoco me muestra el resultado por pantalla si le hago un print. Gracias por la ayuda. ¿Quizás me sirva si en vez de 1024 le pongo 512 o menos?

Comment: No... `find()` no forma parte del api de un archivo. Creo que puedes usar `stdout.read()` para obtener su contenido. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp